# How to create web API and MVC solution separately?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to the .net application.  am trying to develop an application for Accounting Purpose. Am totally confused that how can I use the design pattern, MVC is preferred. I have to use this app both in Desktop and as a mobile app. App should be more secure.

So please guide me how to design the project. Can you please suggest any examples?

1. WebApi + MVC is good option I think but for this, should I create 2 solution for both API and MVC?
2. should it work smart phone as well as desktop?

Database-PostgreSQL

Application will have two parts:

Part I – Accessible to the client through the web page

Part II – Back-end accessible only to us (Company) where all the processing is carried out. Perform the initial setup once the client is registered – create the account in the accounting software and create the chart of accounts

1. Review and process documents
2. Accounting – the entries will be passed in the application and will be exported to the accounting software

Comment: Whilst this is an interesting question, it is either too broad or matter-of-opinion for Stack Overflow, and may end up in a discussion rather than Q&A. You may therefore find this is put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can find many tutorials out there on the web about creating a `ASP.NET MVC` project with `Web API`.

This can be achieved in one solution as you will see in tutorials.

Example: [Getting started with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

For the desktop and mobile support, I would like to refer to use `Responsive Design`. Using a library like [GetBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) you can create websites that change their content dynamically for each type of device ( desktop / tablets / smartphones / ... ).

Answer (score 0):

Now-a-days everything is mobile. So if you are developing something both for Web and mobile app, API has to be the first and only choice.

The reason behind is that--- More or less what Web shows, APP should also show that, but the layouts or UI are different(here comes the client-side). Moreover if APP needs some extra API, I do not think, that would be much overhead if certain extra APIs are written for the APP. Essentially One API codebase suffices both the paradigms.
It is always a good idea to seperate Client-side architecture with server-side architecture.

I would suggest to seperate the client and server(API), and that would be in best of interest.
Your .net application may serve as client side with MVC pattern where M can call API services and C as usually manages the business logic and V displays the results.
You can write API services(server/backend) in .net, nodeJS, PHP, GO any technology which can manage talking to servers. There also you can create certain architecture or flow of your requests.
Hope that helps